How is LAX for Delta domestic connections?
I've tried researching this, but it appears that the inter-terminal walkways (vs bus) introduced around a year ago has changed things.
If I were to book a Delta connection through LAX would I likely have to change terminals and, if so, how much time should I budget for that?

More information is needed in order to respond. Any of these factors may affect the answer: Where are you flying from? Where are you flying to? What country's passport or travel document do you carry? Will you have checked luggage? Are both flights on one ticket with a single PNR? If a single ticket, was it purchased directly from Delta?

@DavidRecallsMonica: why would passport matter for a domestic connection?

@Hilmar While the title says "domestic connection," we don't know if this is domestic incoming, domestic outgoing, or domestic-to-domestic. Thus the conditional "may affect the answer" in my earlier comment.

Usually flights from a given airline  are to and from the same terminal, for example, Delta (and Aeromexico) are at Terminal 3 at LAX and if you arrive and leave on a Delta flight you don't have to go to another terminal or go through security again. Do you know that's somehow not the case for you? Or maybe I misunderstood the question...

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany "flights from a given airline are to and from the same terminal" may be true at LAX, but is not universal for all airlines and all terminals. ATL has 2 terminals with 7 concourses, and Delta flies out of all of them.

It would probably be easier if you told us where from and where to you are flying. Even on domestic-domestic, the route can be as easy and walking across the departures hall or slightly more complex, having to move to another terminal (without the need to clear security, though). Delta's situation is probably simpler than some other airlines at LAX, but they're still present in 3 different terminals...

According to Delta's website, Delta flights may arrive and depart from Terminals 2, 3, and B at LAX. These terminals are all connected airside via moving walkways, so there should be no need to reclear security or wait for a bus for a domestic connection. I don't think you need to allow any more time than you would for a connection at any other large airport.

DavidRecallsMonica, I am asking about domestic flights, so passports are not a consideration.

Spehro, thank you for the useful information.

shoover, thank you very much for the useful information.

jcaron, thank you for the reply.
The connecting flights will be to/from SMF (Sacramento) and to/from MCO (Orlando) or TPA (Tampa).
